# Is there a way to remove links in HTML if a condition is not met?

Tags: html, django

I want to remove "a href" if a certain condition is met. In my case, when the word "None" appears, i do not want it to have a link.

html:

```
{% for item in responses %}
        <tr>               
            <td style="border: 1px solid"><div style="height: 200px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden"><a href="/media/{{ item.Document.Filename }}">{{ item.Document.Document_name }}</a></div></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

So if {{ item.Document.Document_name }} == "None", i do not want it to have hyperlink

Comment: OK so what's stopping you having an `if` tag there?

Comment: I am not sure how to use the if statement properly

Comment: @Lloyd did you try reading [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/)? Django has a very extensive documentation which explains everything you needed to know and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Document_name` as string - `'None'` in your db, then there's an example how you can change your code.

```
{% for item in responses %}
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid">
            <div style="height: 200px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden">
            {% if item.Document.Document_name == 'None' %}
                <a href="/media/{{ item.Document.Filename }}">{{ item.Document.Document_name }}</a>
            {% else %}
                {{ item.Document.Document_name }}
            {$ endif %}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did something similar and it works